# Connecting a VB.NET 2010 app to a LAN Server MySql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want my vb application to communicate with a MySql database on server on a LAN. What connection string can i use? Also, what syntax can i use? My application is installed on many computers in LAN with one central MySql database. I want all data to go to the database.

Comment: There are several steps involved so just concentrate on getting a simple connection working first on 1 machine to the DB. The reply here is good on how to proceed: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/878d58e5-0f54-4cde-b8b5-e66ee92d53ce/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For connection strings try [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql) (1st result when googling '**MySQL Connection String**')